# What is the difference in meaning between the sentences?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference in meaning between the two sentences?

> 1. I want to travel the moon.
> 2. I want to travel to the moon.

Comment: The first one probably means "I want to travel (around) the moon" (different places on the moon). Omitted prepositions are common but can lead to misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are saying that you want to explore the moon. If you drop the "to" before a place name, you are implying that you are exploring the area. In the second case, the "To" is implied, and you are just saying that you would like to go to the moon or go on a trip to the moon.

Answer (score 0):

"To travel to the moon" means to go to the moon but not necessarily to do anything once you are there or even to come back.

"To travel the moon" means to travel around to different places on the moon.

If you are not already on the moon, you would have to travel to the moon before you could travel the moon.

Answer (score 0):

Travel to the moon means you want to make the trip to get there. Travel the moon means you want to fully explore it. Good luck with that.